# Header to begin absolute and become fixed after scrolling passed the next section

Tags: jquery, html, css, header, css-transitions

Basically, I want the header to be absolutely positioned so when you start to scroll down, it remains in place and isn't visibile until I pass the next section. At that point, I want it to become fixed and translateY into view, and the reversed when scrolling back to the top.

I have 90% of it figured out, though I can only get the transform to transition while scrolling down. When scrolling back up, the transition breaks. I've tried throwing all sorts of different classes at it depending on where the scroll position is but nothing is working. I know having two menus would solve my problem, but that is not something I'd ever consider.

Here's a video of how I have it now, you'll see it not transition when scrolling back up:
https://vid.me/wUwx

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope this helps

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var windowsize = $window.height();
if (windowsize >= 400) { // Some Number of height
$('.header').css('position','fixed');
}
else {
$('.header').css('position','relative');
}
});
```

And header class should have a 100% width

Comment: That's a simplified version of what I have already, except the header is absolute instead of relative so it scrolls out of view at first.

Comment: You shouldn't use absolute for header's, absolute refers to bring out the element further up! What exactly is your problem? I can't get a sketch!